# Logistic Regression model keeps kicking out 1 dummy

Tags: r, logistic

I have a dataset in which each row belongs to one of 8 categories. I'm running a logistic regrssion on it using R. I created dummy variables for each of these categories. In my logistic regression model I know one of these dummies need to be excluded to not fall for the dummy variable trap. However the model keeps kicking out the same dummy-variable, even if I exclude another. I thought, maybe this dummy is kicked out due to other variables (other than the other dummy variables), but after using only the category-dummies to estimate the model, that particular variable still results in NA.

Why is this? Am I missing something?

Example: (I've removed all other variables and just included the first 100 rows of the dependent variable + the category dummies)

```
 structure(list(buy = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cat1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), cat2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cat3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
cat4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), cat5 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cat6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cat7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cat8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("buy", "cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", 
"cat5", "cat6", "cat7", "cat8"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

For the logistic regression I use:

```
mylogit <- glm(formula= buy ~ cat1 + cat2 + cat4 + cat5 + cat6 + cat7 + cat8, family = binomial, data=df)
```

As shown in the output of this model, cat7 is NA

```
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -2.6626     0.5972  -4.459 8.24e-06 ***
cat1          -17.9035  2769.0186  -0.006    0.995    
cat2          -17.9035 17730.3699  -0.001    0.999    
cat4            1.0531     1.2476   0.844    0.399    
cat5          -17.9035 17730.3699  -0.001    0.999    
cat6          -17.9035  8865.1850  -0.002    0.998    
cat7                NA         NA      NA       NA    
cat8          -17.9035 17730.3699  -0.001    0.999
```

However, 1 of the dummies should be excluded. If I exclude for instance cat 6 by leaving it out of the equation or by using '- cat6' the results for cat7 are still NA.

Comment: Can you post your R code and a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), please? If the response variable has 8 levels, don't you think that a multinomial or ordinal logistic regression might do the job as well?

Comment: Like @chl I'd like to see your code, but it sounds like you are simply running the same regression on different subsets of your data; if you exclude one level of your variable, R will just run on the other levels with the same defaults and use the same level as the reference (unless you exclude it).

Comment: chl Those 8 categories are not the only variables available. There are a lot of more indepdent variables used. 

@PeterFlom This sounds familiar. I do not change anything to the dataset, but just add/remove the variable from the glm() function. It is not excluded than? If not. How to do so.

I will try to extend this question with a reproducible example.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing without code, but it *sounds* like you are excluding some data, whereas what you want to do is change the reference category for a factor variable.

Comment: @PeterFlom I've added the example data

Comment: OK, given that code, our suspicions were correct. `-cat6` just deletes that level. There's a way to do what you want, but I am not sure what it is in `R`; a more experienced `R` person will doubtless know.

Comment: Well thank you for helping me to construct a more solid question. Lets hope that someone knows how to do the trick.

Comment: You data have problem... first there are still many rows that have zero, indicating that they don't belong to any category. (a quick tabulation shows that 32 cases have not been assigned to any group, 1 case was assigned to two groups, only 67 of them seem correct.) Second, your cat5 and cat7 are perfectly collinear. That's why it's still being kicked out after you have removed cat6. I am guessing your categorization script that made the dummies might have some typos due to copy and paste, go check that.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight The fact that there are rows that have no category can be due to the fact I took only the first 100 rows of my 15million+ dataset. However: you do have a great point on the collinearity. Due to an error in the script, these are indeed the same. Will fix that immediately and check again.

Comment: @Max Great! Hopefully that'd solve your mystery.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Works like a charm now... Pretty straight forward! Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, post as answer? Your comments that lead to the solution are buried (and now I added to the pile!).

Comment: @BenBarnes Sure, will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some problems with the data:

First there are still many rows that have zero, indicating that they don't belong to any of the 8 categories. A quick tabulation shows that 32 cases have not been assigned to any group, 1 case was assigned to two groups, only 67 of them seem correct.

Second, the variables cat5 and cat7 are perfectly collinear. That's why it's still being kicked out after you have removed cat6. I am guessing your categorization script that made the dummies might have some typos due to copy and paste, go check that.